# Edmond's blossom algorithm for Max weight perfect matchings

Tags: graph-theory, perfect-matchings

Edmond's blossom algorithm computes a maximum weight matching in a general graph (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm).
Many papers also reference to Edmond's blossom algorithm to compute a Maximum weight *perfect* matching. I don't understand how this is possible. Given for instance the following graph (a square with one diagonal):

V={0,1,2,3}, E={(0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,0),(0,2)}. All edges have weight one, except the diagonal edge (0,2) which has weight 10.

A maximum weight perfect matching would be M1={(0,1),(2,3)} with weight 2. However a maximum weight (non-perfect) matching in the same graph would be M2={(0,2)} with weight 10.
So how can the same algorithm be used to compute a perfect matching?

See for instance the introduction in the following papers:

1. [Kolmogorov
   Blossom, V: a new implementation of a minimum cost
   perfect matching algorithm](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/930b/9f9c3bc7acf3277dd2361076d40ff03774b2.pdf)
2. [Cook, Rohe, Computing Minimum-Weight Perfect Matchings](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~bico/papers/match_ijoc.pdf)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose you have a graph with edge weights $w_e$.  Add constant $M > \sum_e |w_e|$ to all the weights, obtaining $w'_e = M + w_e$.  If there is a perfect matching, its (primed) weight is greater than the (primed) weight of any non-perfect matching.  Thus the matching of maximum (primed) weight is a maximum-weight perfect matching.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be correct. Here's a counter example (cycle graph with 2 extra edges).
V={0,1,2,3,4,5} E={(0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,0), (1,3),(0,4)}. All edges have weight 1, except edges (1,3),(0,4) which have weight 10.
Set M=11. Then all edges have weight 11, except edges (1,3),(0,4) which have weight 21.

A maximum weight perfect matching would be M1={(0,1),(2,3),(4,5)} with weight 33. However, the non-perfect matching M2={(1,3),(0,4)} has weight 42.
Could you confirm this?

Comment: Oops, meant sum rather than max.  Editing.

Comment: Yes that seems to work. Is this a known transformation (reference?), or did you come up with this?

Comment: A well-known strategy to enforce a constraint is to add an appropriate  term to the objective.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably if all the weights are equal, the the maximum matching is a perfect matching, so that weighting can be used to find a perfect matching if there is one. All the references I can find use the Edmonds algorithm to find the maximum matching, not necessarily perfect.